# Sending messages from file system html page to a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to creating chrome extensions.  I want to test sending messages from a web page to an extension as described here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage.

I'd like to just use an html file in my file system, like "file:///C:/Users/johng/Documents/TestExtensionCall.html", to do the initial testing but the developer documentation indicates that you need to include "externally_connectable" in your extension manifest to expose the messaging api and the url pattern must include a second-level domain.

Can an html file from the file system be used to test sending messages from a web page to a chrome extension?  Do I actually need to use a web page from a web site to do the testing?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

For testing `externally_connectable`, you have<sup>1</sup> to use a web server.

Though, you can still use a local development web server. Normally, it would have a `localhost` hostname, but you can specify an alias for it in your DNS hosts file, say, `my.localhost`, and it would satisfy Chrome's requirements.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) for more information about the hosts file.

<sup>1</sup> *To the best of my knowledge*