# Send data from page to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I trying send some data from my web application to my chrome extension (like it described in the [google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)), but I have an error: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

My content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.url == blocklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
      openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
  });
```

And it's my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "test-extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["src/bg/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost/*"],
      "js": ["src/inject/inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "ids": ["abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc"],
    "matches": ["http://localhost/*"],
    "accepts_tls_channel_id": false
  }
}
```

And test page, where I'm trying to send data:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="processData()">Send data to extension</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    function processData() {
      /* ... */
      // The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
      var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

      // Make a simple request:
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        editorExtensionId,
        { openUrlInEditor: 'https://google.com' },
        function(response) {
          if (!response.success) handleError(url);
        }
      );
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You can probably add a dummy domain in your `hosts` file that points to 127.0.0.1 and then use that domain name in externally_connectable. Try searching for an existing answer if you need more details.

Comment: @wOxxOm it's doesn't work, i tried a lot of combinations

Comment: "It" is a vague description. Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24838438) of what I meant, you can look for more detailed ones.

Comment: @wOxxOm thx! now It is working!

Comment: @PavelGrekovich I am trying the same thing, I have content js but not background js.

Is background js is mandatory for this ?
I am building extension through nextjs

Comment: In your frontend code how do u have access to variable `chrome` @wOxxOm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was been in `the externally_connectable` configuration. It's dosen't work with `localhost`. For work with it on the `localhost` I added in my host file this lines:

```
127.0.0.1 my.localhost
```

Then changed manifest to:

```
 "externally_connectable": {
    "ids": ["*"],
    "matches": [
      "http://my.localhost/*",
    ]
```

Comment: Message from future FWIW: in my case localhost works fine, though I'm using `https` and also specified a port (`"https://localhost:1234/*"`)

Answer (score 0):

> This will expose the messaging API to any page which matches the URL patterns you specify. The URL pattern must contain at least a second-level domain - that is, hostname patterns like "*", "*.com", "*.co.uk", and "*.appspot.com" are prohibited. From the web page, use the runtime.sendMessage or runtime.connect APIs to send a message to a specific app or extension

ref: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Maybe it's because of your http://localhost/*